# Foreign key for array column

Tags: postgresql, array, referential-integrity

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE methods
(
    method_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    method_name varchar(100)
);
```

I now want to create a table with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE experiments 
(
    method integer[] REFERENCES methods(method_id),
    trials integer
);
```

I get an error:

> Key columns "method" and "method_id" are of incompatible types: integer[] and integer.

I understand that the columns have to be the same type and I also saw that some tried to tackle this foreign key on array issue already:

[PostgreSQL 9.3 development: Array ELEMENT Foreign Keys](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-3-development-array-element-foreign-keys/)

My interest is that 'method' should be an array of integers referencing 'method_id' from table 'methods' but I can't figure it out. I thought that the link above might be a solution, but seems that was not implemented (?)

Some posts propose using junction/join tables:

[Foreign key constraint on array member?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60132/foreign-key-constraint-on-array-member)

I am an absolute beginner and I could not figure it out yet. For me, it is a matter of understanding first how to tackle this issue of a foreign key on an array. Multiple methods can be considered as forming a class of methods. Each class can have a certain number of trials.

Answer (score 6):

As you simply cannot create a foreign key against an array column, you should store the experiments in the proper relational way.  This is what you mention as a junction table.

It is a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE experiments (
    method_id integer REFERENCES methods (method_id),
    method_class_id integer REFERENCES method_class (method_class_id)
);
```

Here you will have one row per method-class pair (which, in turn, may mean several trials, based on your comments above), instead of just one per trial as in your current design.  This means a slight storage overhead, but it gives you the flexibility - queries will use proper joins which can be supported by indexes, for example.  Also, removing methods from a class will be much easier.

**Note:** I suppose above that you have a `method_class` table, too.

Comment: Hi @dezso! Thanks for your reply. I am afraid that I don't understand what  "trials" table is in this context and how should look like.

Comment: @ValSt well, I got _your_ table definition above to guess what you want.  So, it's _you_ who should know what `trials` is about.  If you manage to describe this in English (as opposed to any programming (pseudo)language), as DeadEye asks for, it could help a lot understanding your requirements.  At the same time, I'd suggest getting a good book or tutorial about relational databases and data modeling.